# How can I pass a variable from imacros to a javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, eval, imacros

I need to multiply a value from imacros with a javascript value.
I can pass the javascript value to imacros, but imacros unable to multiply it.
Also, I didn't find any solution, how to extract a variable from imacros and pass it to a javascript.

```
var macro, iret;
var JsNumber = 5;

function macro1()

{
   iimSet("VAR1", JsNumber);
   macro = "CODE:";
   macro += "VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX\n";
   macro += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE c:\\database.csv\n";
   macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1\n";
   macro += "SET !VAR2 {{!COL1}}\n";
   macro += "SET !VAR3 EVAL(VAR1 * VAR2)\n";
   macro += "PROMPT {{!VAR3}} !VAR4\n";
   iret = iimPlay(macro)
}

{
   macro1();
}
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you have tried, and then describe where you are having problem.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the code. My problem is with the EVAL line, because if I add more quotation marks imacros won't like it. What is would like is: to multiply VAR1 with VAR2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var macro, iret;
var JsNumber = 5;


var theReturn=macro1(JsNumber);


function macro1(JsNumber)

{
   iimSet("VAR1", JsNumber);
   macro = "CODE:";
   macro += "VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX\n";
   macro += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE c:\\database.csv\n";
   macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1\n";
   macro += "SET !VAR2 {{!COL1}}\n";
   macro += "SET !VAR3 EVAL(VAR1 * VAR2)\n";
   macro += "SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR3}}\n";
   macro += "PROMPT {{!VAR3}} !VAR4\n";
   iret = iimPlay(macro)

   var ret=iimGetLastExtract();

return ret;

}
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: iimGetExtract()
This can give a variable FROM the imacros script TO the javascript.